# Rails Rake db:migrate aborting (sqlite3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, dbmigrate

Similar questions have been asked but none of the recommendations have worked for me.  I'm trying to migrate a db in rails development on my computer and I keep getting this error message:

```
 rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined local variable or method `total' for #<CreateProfessors:0x007f8ce3ca4e60>/Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:664:in `block in method_missing'
   /Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-   4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/Users/tfantina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
```

It continues on for a hundred lines or so.
One of the posts here recommended removing

```
null: false
```

from

```
  t.timestamps null:false
```

which I did.

Another recommendation I have tried is running db:drop:all then db:create:all then db:migrate.

To make sure sqlite3 was on my OSX I ran a sqlite3 query in terminal and was returned:  SQLite version 3.8.10.2 so I assume that's working properly.

Failing migration:

```
    class CreateProfessors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :professors do |t|
      t.string :fname
      t.string :lname
      t.decimal :rating-total
      t.decimal :rating-hw
      t.decimal :rating-test
      t.decimal :rating-interest
      t.text :comments
      t.string :ease

      t.timestamps 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please, paste your last migration or the failing migration

Comment: I have added the failing migration, it's the only one I've done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These column names are illegal:

```
t.decimal :rating-total
t.decimal :rating-hw
t.decimal :rating-test
t.decimal :rating-interest
```

It should be: (use `_` instead of `-`)

```
t.decimal :rating_total
t.decimal :rating_hw
t.decimal :rating_test
t.decimal :rating_interest
```

Comment: Hey hey!  That's it.  Thanks, I'm super new to Rails so this is pretty basic but I appreciate it I was really stuck.